# How to unbold citation number in amsproc class

Tags: bibliographies, bold, amsproc

```
\documentclass{amsproc}

\begin{document}

def \cite{abc}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{abc} abc
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

I am using the `amsproc` class to typeset a math document. The citation number `[1]` in the text comes up bold. I think it would look nicer if it were not bold. Is there a way to unbold it? Or is there a similar package I should use in which this is not bold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class uses

```
\def\citeform#1{{\bfseries#1}}
```

so you need to remove `\bfseries`:

```
\documentclass{amsproc}

\renewcommand\citeform[1]{{#1}}

\begin{document}

def \cite{abc}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{abc} abc
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are submitting the document to a journal, most probably they will override the change.

Comment: `\renewcommand`, not `\def`, please! :) I'd keep the inner braces anyway.